# Issue In extracting desired data from the Json Response

Tags: java, json

My Json response looks like this:

```
{
    "oAuthClientResponse": {
    "grantTypes": [
        "client_credentials",
        "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
    ],
    "appId": "0e0da052-baab-4e86-a826-edfcaadbd93b",
    "certAlias": "tenant_269869150664042.st2Oauth.st2Oauth_svc_269869150693042_st2_client_OAUTHCLIENT.cert",
    "clientCertificate": "MIIC",
    "paramList": null,
    "audiences": [
        "http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RW",
        "http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RO"
    ],
    "isDisabled": "false",
    "clientMetadata": {
        "isTenantManaged": "false",
        "isTrusted": "true"
    },
    "activityData": {
        "createdOn": "08/10/2015 02:15:55"
    },
    "tenant": "tenant_269869150664042",
    "description": "st2Oauth_svc_269869150693042_st2_client_OAUTHCLIENT",
    "name": "st2Oauth_svc_269869150693042_st2_client_OAUTHCLIENT",
    "appSecret": "EghTRToAFJUWHrsnXlK5",
    "clientType": "CONFIDENTIAL_CLIENT"
    }
}
```

I want to read the value of audiences.

```
String value = jObject.getJSONObject("oAuthClientResponse").getString(
                    "audiences");
```

In value I am getting :

```
"audiences": [
    "http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RW",
    "http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RO"
]
```

Now I am not able to extract the value of the audiences.i.e.

```
http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RW   and
http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RO
```

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getJSONArray()` instead of `getString()`

```
JSONArray audiences = jObject.getJSONObject("oAuthClientResponse")
                             .getJSONArray("audiences");
```

Then you can retrieve the individual values using indices

```
System.out.println(audiences.getString(0)); // http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RW
System.out.println(audiences.getString(1)); // http://svc.com/EndPoint/st2/CommonApi::RO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = jObject.getJSONObject("oAuthClientResponse").getString(
                "audiences");
value = value.subString(value.indexOf('['))
value = value.replace("[","");
value = value.replace("]","");
value = value.replace("\"","");
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
                    actualOutput, ",");
while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
      String value = (String) lineTokenizer.nextElement();
      System.out.println(value)
}
```